# Setting rotue/path-names dynamically according to language

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building my first multi-language application. Successfully detecting the language via Middelware and attaching it to req.lang. As a next step, is there any way to also localize the route-paths? This would be very useful for SEO.

What is the ususal approach here?

```
const paths = {
  en: {
    index: 'home',
    imprint: 'imprint'
  },
  de: {
    index: 'start',
    imprint: 'impressum'
  },
  nl: {
    index: 'stchartje',
    imprint: 'imprintjn'
  }

}

router.get('/'+paths[req.lang].imprint, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: content[req.lang].IMPRINT.HEADLINE });
})
```

Thats what I came up with for now, it is not working though, because 'req' is not evailable in the route-definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `params`:

```
router.get('/:slug', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.params.slug === paths[req.lang].imprint) {
      res.render('index', { title: content[req.lang].IMPRINT.HEADLINE });
  } else {
      next();
  }

})
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, this works pretty well. Do you think this is performance-wise ok, too?